# Some questions around Corda function feature

Tags: jetty, jmx, corda

1. how corda node to do high available? (1. Container way or 2. Corda way)?
2. could I install the second jetty server with same restful interface to  rpc invoke the same client node as well the first jetty server for  flow?
3. future plan ( like mesos auto deploy in multiple machine)?
4. JMX monitor active MQ messages, queues, topic?
5. Jetty performance or function set as it embed into core code, sample if I want to set a filter that very hard to not touch core project? Performance parameter how to set?
6. JPA  Custom Query if have set a flag let it not involve Vault table for offline chain to use?
7. How to design sample for a table to associate a foreign key to another table?
8. Shell script how to communicate with Corda Node?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  These should be separate questions at a minimum.  Also stackoverflow is about software development/coding, a typical good question will show what you have tried, what errors you are getting, and asking for specific help on a narrow topic.  Questions asking for recommendations produce poor quality answers and are generally not a good fit for stackoverflow.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Indeed @JoaKimErdfelt is right.. It's very difficult to answer the above when some of them aren't even questions and all of them in one post may get to be quite a large answer.

Comment: ok， thx for suggest , I will re-validate questions. actually I only want to know the Corda HA strategy

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of questions! forgive me if I've misunderstood them here but I'll do my best to answer them.

1. not exactly sure what you mean here but corda has built in redundancy features and you can run corda nodes in containers as well (here's an example repo doing so: https://github.com/EricMcEvoyR3/corda-docker-compose)
2. So we now recommend using spring boot servers to build an HTTP server on top of a corda node. Take a look here for an example : https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp
3. Here's a link to the corda planned features page: https://www.corda.net/platform-roadmap/ it's not super thorough but it covers the basics.
4. Corda has some JMX integrations you can find out more about them here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-administration.html#monitoring-via-jolokia
5. Corda jetty webservers are basically deprecated, here's another blog post on how to migrate off of them: https://www.corda.net/blog/spring-cleaning-migrating-your-cordapp-away-from-the-deprecated-corda-jetty-web-server/
6. The corda docs have a whole page on the JPA and how it's supported, you can find more here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/api-persistence.html
7. This depends entirely on your cordapp and the data you're trying to model. It's not something that's easy to help with here, I will say however that usually it's not necessary for most cordapps to do this.
8. You can use the corda shell to communicate with the corda node, more info on that here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html